# Сортировка Mongo без вывода дубликатов

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

моя задача сделать сортировку по **city_id** в MongoDB Compass но на выводе не должно быть дубликатов записи одного и того же юзера.

Конструкция .find().distinct() не работает

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачу

Например есть такая база в mongo

```
  {
    user_id: 1,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 1,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 1,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
];
```

Должен быть следующий результат

```
  {
    user_id: 1,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    city_id: 10,
    description: "Покупка",
  }
```

Comment: Пробуй так `db.test.aggregate({$group: {_id: 'user_id'} , {$sort: {user_id: 1}}})`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.